# Adding a button and macro to the last row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a stock taking spreadsheet for a small company, with very **very** novice Excel users. As such I want to use macros and VBA to do most of the work so they don't get overwhelmed by having to edit formula or create charts. In an ideal world they would learn some excel, but the reality is that isn't going to happen.

So far I have a nice userform that makes input easy and once the submit button is pressed, it inserts all the data on to a stock list on the first available row. However, I also want to put a button at the end of each row that they can press if an item is subsequently sold. I have written a macro for this ("Sale") that decreases the item quantity, moves the item details to a sold sheet, and deletes the row entirely if the quantity goes to zero. My problem is that I cannot get the submit button of my userform to add in a macro button to a variable row number.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Stock Warehouse")
    LRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Set rng = ws.Cells(LRow, 23)

    With ws
    .Cells(LRow, 1).Value = Date
    .Cells(LRow, 2).Value = Me.CATEGORY.Value

     (---etc etc until---)

    .Cells(LRow, 21).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(rc[-1]/rc[-11])"

    rng.Select
    ws.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.RowHeight).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Sale"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "SALE"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=4).Font
    .Name = "Lucida Grande"
    (---more formatting stuff---)
    End With
```

If I set it to go to a named cell (i.e. "W5") it works and inserts the button. It's just getting it to insert a button in LRow, 23 that is so problematic! It's probably pretty straight forward but I have been staring at this for days and can't figure it out.

Comment: You forgot to qualify the row? `LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`

Comment: Although your post describes very well the context, I still fail to grasp completely the problem. Your `rng` is set to `(LRow, 23)`, you insert a button there, and you get it inserted there. What is the problem exactly, then? Is it that you want to insert such button at the end of *each* row? If so, it is a very simple loop, no?

Comment: And by the way, did you envisage using a drop down menu using the mouse right-click? I have a similar application that drops a menu with adjusted content according to the mouse position (row). It is much more practical and aestectic than filling too many buttons on the worksheet. The user would place the mouse over a cell, right-click, and click the menu item "Sale".

Comment: @findwindow I dont think that this causes a problem, unless the workbook is a pre-2007 version open in compatibility mode.

Comment: @A.S.H OP didn't specify what the issue was. That was my first thought.

Comment: The problem was that the button *wasn't* inserting in to Lrow, 23 when I ran the macro. No button was appearing at all. It might be because I'm using Excel on a mac and it seems that VBA is a bit  dodgy at times on the mac version. The right click menu is a much better idea though, I've coded that in instead. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it inserts the button okay, but it would be better to avoid the selects

```
    Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.RowHeight)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "Sale"
        .Characters.Text = "SALE"
        With .Characters.Font
            .Name = "Lucida Grande"
'        (---more formatting stuff---)
        End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having one button which stays put above a freeze-pane line, and users select a/any cell (you can tell/train them which one) in the row they want to delete/process/whatever, and then press the button? Have the button detect the row (with appropriate checks) using ActiveCell.Row and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but it was two buttons and they moved depending on the selected row, that way the user could scroll the data and the buttons would show up when they selected the row they wanted. I used pictures as my buttons and assigned macros to them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 2")
    .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
    .Left = 930
End With
With ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 4")
    .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
    .Left = 1005
End With
End Sub
```

It always displays to the right of the data and down 1 row so as not to cover up any notes I had in there.

Edit:

Using this method you can also make it work on a selection if the user selects a bunch of rows and runs the code by using `Selection.Rows.Count` and looping the code using an offset.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting solution and looks nicer than hundreds of buttons!